# Using Function in Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

`Reference` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ref_uharian]
(
    [uhID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [uh_tahun] [int] NOT NULL,
    [uh_kdlokasi] [int] NOT NULL,
    [uh_nominal] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ref_uharian] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [uh_tahun] ASC,
    [uh_kdlokasi] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

`Master` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[master_st]
(
    [tugasID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nost_generate] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [nost_asli] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [nip] [varchar](18) NULL,
    [kdperan] [int] NULL,
    [gol] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [eselon] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [kdst] [int] NOT NULL,
    [kdlokasi] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tgl_mulai] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [tgl_selesai] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [jumlahhari1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [jumlahhari2] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_master_st] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [tugasID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`TRANSACTION DETAIL` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[trs_uangharian]
(
    [tr_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tugasID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [uangharian20] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [uangharian80] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [uangharian100] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_trs_uangharian] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [tr_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I want to do is create a trigger so that when I insert a row into the `MASTER` table, it will insert new values into the `TRANSACTION DETAIL` based on table `Reference`.

```
uangharian100
uangharian20 (is 20% from uangharian 100)
uangharian80 (is 80% from uangharian 100)
```

to get the value of uangharian100 i have make a function (it has to do because [tgl_mulai] varchar datebegin and [tgl_mulai] varchar dateend is a varchar so I have to convert it to date first.

This is the Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fc_col_uangharian100]
(
    @tgl_mulai VARCHAR(10),
    @tgl_selesai VARCHAR(10),
    @kdlokasi INT
)
RETURNS DECIMAL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @date_diff INT,  @thn_harian INT, @cst_uharian DECIMAL (15,2)

    SET @thn_harian=CAST(YEAR(CONVERT(datetime, @tgl_mulai, 103)) AS INT)
    SET @date_diff=((SELECT datediff(day,CONVERT([datetime],@tgl_mulai,(103)),CONVERT([datetime],@tgl_selesai,(103))))+1)
    SET @cst_uharian=(SELECT uh_nominal FROM ref_uharian WHERE ((uh_tahun=@thn_harian) AND (uh_kdlokasi=@kdlokasi)))

    RETURN ((@date_diff)*(@cst_uharian))
END
```

Comment: can you show us your trigger code ?

Comment: Your question is not much clear,please show some sample data on both tables and explain with expected output

Comment: assume i have a reference table  [dbo].[ref_uharian] for traveling to german (code location 1) for year 2016 (uh_tahun) is 500. In master tabel i insert one (or people) name that go to german (date departure and date return). Lets say 17/05/2016 until 20/05/2016 (4 days). But the date type in master table is varchar. What i want to achieved is make a trigger to detai transact (for that travel ---> cost is 4 days * 500 =2000)